# Ngrok tunneling to dockerised symfony 5 ends in 502 bad gateway

Tags: php, docker, symfony, ngrok

I have a brand new symfony 5 app in a docker container, on which I need to receive some webhook, thus using ngrok for tunneling. Thing is, ngrok keep sending me 502 errors, whereas the localhost access is doing fine.
I'm kinda running out of ideas.

Curl using localhost:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:4080/default
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 4080 (#0)
> GET /default HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:4080
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache, private
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2020 09:10:43 GMT
< PHP message: [info] Matched route "default".
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.3
< X-Robots-Tag: noindex
< Content-Length: 93
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"message":"Welcome to your new controller!","path":"src\/Controller\/DefaultController.php"}
```

Docker logs while using localhost:

```
payment_1                 | [Web Server/PHP ] Jul 23 09:10:43 |INFO | PHP    PHP message: Matched route "default". path="/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm" php="7.4.3"
payment_1                 | [Web Server/PHP ] Jul 23 09:10:43 |DEBUG| PHP     
payment_1                 | [Web Server/PHP ] Jul 23 09:10:43 |INFO | SERVER GET  (200) ]8;;https://127.0.0.1:8004/default\/default]8;;\ ip="172.20.0.1"
```

Ngrok started with:

```
$ ngrok http 4080
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                                                                                                                                          (Ctrl+C to quit)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Session Status                online                                                                                                                                                                               
Account                       lulhum (Plan: Free)                                                                                                                                                                  
Version                       2.3.35                                                                                                                                                                               
Region                        United States (us)                                                                                                                                                                   
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                                                                                                                
Forwarding                    http://8c882c861512.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:4080                                                                                                                                
Forwarding                    https://8c882c861512.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:4080                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                                                                                                                                          
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Curl through ngrok:

```
$ curl -v http://8c882c861512.ngrok.io/default
*   Trying 3.137.63.131...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 8c882c861512.ngrok.io (3.137.63.131) port 80 (#0)
> GET /default HTTP/1.1
> Host: 8c882c861512.ngrok.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
< Content-length: 107
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
<html><body><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.
</body></html>
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Closing connection 0
```

Docker logs through ngrok (same as before):

```
payment_1                 | [Web Server/PHP ] Jul 23 09:17:07 |INFO | PHP    PHP message: Matched route "default". path="/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm" php="7.4.3"
payment_1                 | [Web Server/PHP ] Jul 23 09:17:07 |DEBUG| PHP     
payment_1                 | [Web Server/PHP ] Jul 23 09:17:07 |INFO | SERVER GET  (200) ]8;;https://127.0.0.1:8004/default\/default]8;;\ ip="172.20.0.1"
```

Ngrok console (seems ok):

```
HTTP Requests                                                                                                                                                                                                      
-------------                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
GET /default                   200 OK
```

The docker container is lauched with symfony dev server via docker compose (docker-compose.yml extract):

```
version: '3'
services:

  payment:
    build: ./payment
    command: sh -c "symfony server:stop && symfony server:start --port=4080"
    environment:
      APP_DEBUG: 1
      VAR_DUMPER_SERVER: payment_dump:8000
    volumes:
      - "./payment:/app"
      - "payment_composer:/root/composer"
    expose:
      - 4080
    ports:
      - "4080:4080"
```

And here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache \
  git \
  curl \
  openssl \
  ssmtp \
  libzip-dev \
  bash

RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
  pcntl \
  zip

RUN apk add --no-cache icu-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install intl

RUN wget https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer -O - | bash \
    && mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony

RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/composer/getcomposer.org/d3e09029468023aa4e9dcd165e9b6f43df0a9999/web/installer | php -- --quiet \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

WORKDIR /app

ENV TZ="Europe/Paris"
ENV IS_DOCKER=1
```

I really don't understand what is going wrong. I have other container with similar configurations that seems to work fine.
I've tried rebuilding the container, and various ngrok commands using *:4080 or http://127.0.0.1:4080, or some -host-header options. Also tried differents ports to no results.
Result is of course the same in browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've narrowed down the issue. The problem is somewhere within symfony server, adding the strange `PHP message: [info] Matched route "default".` header.
This message is issued by the logger and supposed to go to stderr. No idea how it got there.

Since it doesn't follow traditional header syntax, I suppose that ngrok fail to read the headers and fallback to 502.

I have raised an [issue to symfony](https://github.com/symfony/cli/issues/300), and use the basic php server in the meanwhile.